# Getting Maximum function nesting level error in magento 1.8

Tags: magento-1.8, totals

I m stuck with

> Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '400'reached

in **magento version 1.8.0.0**. When i recalculate total in `sales_quote_collect_totals_after` event.The code of observer is as below

```
public function recalculateTotal($observer){
 $quote=$observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
 $quote->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false);
 $quote->getShippingAddress()->unsetData('cached_items_all');
 $quote->getShippingAddress()->unsetData('cached_items_nominal');
 $quote->getShippingAddress()->unsetData('cached_items_nonnominal');
 $quote->collectTotals();
```

}

and the same error occur when i submit my custom form.but if i change form method `POST` to `GET` it works fine.

I can't understand what's going inside it.Please can somebody get out from it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the following:

- `collectTotals` function in `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote.php` triggers the `sales_quote_collect_totals_after` event
- `sales_quote_collect_totals_after` event triggers your `recalculateTotal` observer function
- your `recalculateTotal` function calls `collectTotals`
- and so on, resulting in an infinite loop

My suggestion:

I'm not sure the reason why you wrote this line:

```
$quote->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false);
```

But changing it to:

```
$quote->setTotalsCollectedFlag(true);
```

Will fix the infinite loop issue.